# Error in opennebula installation

Tags: openstack, opennebula

When I install opennebula 5.4 on centos 7.3 ,I can not configure passwordless SSH successfully.

When I install KVM node, I excute `scp -rp /var/lib/one/.ssh xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/lib/one/`,I've this error:

```
oneadmin@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I don't think this should happen here. The password should be unknown to the user. The communication between oneadmin does not need a password. It must be where I was wrong.

There are docs about opennebula installation.(Control Node& Compute Node).

[frontend node](http://docs.opennebula.org/5.4/deployment/opennebula_installation/frontend_installation.html)

[kvm node](http://docs.opennebula.org/5.4/deployment/node_installation/kvm_node_installation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're looking at the step to set up passwordless ssh for the pool: http://docs.opennebula.org/5.4/deployment/node_installation/kvm_node_installation.html#step-4-configure-passwordless-ssh

The docs say:

> Now we need to copy the directory /var/lib/one/.ssh to all the nodes. *The easiest way is to set a temporary password to oneadmin in all the hosts*

The step you are seeing is the one which delivers the keys which are going to be used in future for passwordless connections. you have to type in the password this one time to deliver them - after that there should be no password prompt (and you can remove the oneadmin account password, if desired).